# Fallo al mostrar datos de programa

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy haciendo mi propia versión de un programa que he visto en un tutorial, para poner en práctica lo que he aprendido.

El programa consta de dos clases por ahora. Una clase Nota, encargada de almacenar la información: el mensaje, la fecha de creación, tags para búsquedas, etc. Y otra clase cuaderno, encargada de manejar todo lo referente a la clase Nota.

El problema que tengo es con los métodos modificar y mostrar notas, que me está resultando imposible hacerlo funcionar.

Os muestro el código:

```py
import datetime
""" Importa la clase datetime, que permite, entre otras cosas, dar el atributo fecha de "hoy". """

class Nota:
    """ Contendrá el contenido de cada nota. """
    def __init__(self, mensaje, tags=""):
        """ Inicializará cada vez que se instancie un objeto de la clase nota. Dará los valores pertinentes del contenido de la nota, los tags y la fecha de creación. """
        self.mensaje = mensaje
        self.tags = tags
        self.fecha_creacion = datetime.datetime.now()

    def search(self, criterio):
        """ Devuelve true o false según si la nota tiene el criterio dado. """
        return criterio in self.mensaje or criterio in self.tags



class Cuaderno:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Inicializa la variable id de la instancia cuaderno y al diccionario que contendrá el par _id : Nota()."""
        self._id = 0
        self.notas = {}

    def mostrar_nota(self, notas=None):
        """ Muestra todas las notas o las notas que se le pasen según el filtro. """
        if not notas:
            notas = list(self.notas)
        for nota in self.notas:
            if nota in notas:
              """   print(f"{nota}: {self.notas[nota].values().tags}\n{self.notas[nota].values().mensaje}") """

    def crear_nota(self, mensaje, tags=""):
        """ Crea una nota y le añade un identificador. El contenido de la nota es obligatorio, pero los tags no lo son. """
        self._id += 1
        self.notas[self._id] = Nota(mensaje, tags)
        print("Se ha creado una nueva nota.")

    def eliminar_nota(self, id):
        """ Elimina una nota con un id especificado. Si la nota no existe, muestra un mensaje. """
        if self.comprobar_nota(id):
            self.notas.pop(id)
            print("Nota eleminada.")

    def modificar_nota(self, id, mensaje="", tags=""):
        """ Modifica el tag o el memo de una nota según si se ha pasado o no el valor. """
        if self.comprobar_nota(id):
            """ Comprueba que el id de verdad exista """
            if mensaje:
                self.notas[id].mensaje = mensaje
                print("Mensaje modificado")
            if tags:
                self.notas[id].tags = tags
                print("tags modificados")

    def comprobar_nota(self, id):
        """ Método que servirá para comprobar que el id dado exista. """
        if id in self.notas:
            return True
        else:
            print("Nota no encontrada")
            return False

    def buscar_nota(self, criterio):
        return {nota for nota in self.notas if nota.values().search(criterio)}
```

Bueno, siguiendo el hilo del problema, yo intento que se muestre el contenido de self.notas. Se puede mostrar con todas las notas o con un filtro. Para pasar el filtro, asigno a una variable el resultado de comprobar_nota, clase que a su vez llama a search para comprobar si la nota indicada cumple el criterio. Luego, uso el método mostrar nota con la variable que almacena las notas que cumplían los criterios de evaluación.

Pero al ser mi self.lista un diccionario, se me está complicando bastante.

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

---

Tras mucha ayuda de FJsevilla, he conseguido hacer el programa. Sinceramente, he aprendido muchísimo gracias a ti.

Dejo el código finalizado, por si alguien quiere verlo en algún futuro.

```py
import datetime
""" Importa la clase datetime, que permite, entre otras cosas, dar el atributo fecha de "hoy". """

class Nota:
    """ Contendrá el contenido de cada nota. """
    def __init__(self, mensaje, tags=""):
        """ Inicializará cada vez que se instancie un objeto de la clase nota. Dará los valores pertinentes del contenido de la nota, los tags y la fecha de creación. """
        self.mensaje = mensaje
        self.tags = tags
        self.fecha_creacion = datetime.datetime.now()

    def search(self, criterio):
        """ Devuelve true o false según si la nota tiene el criterio dado. """
        return criterio in self.mensaje or criterio in self.tags



class Cuaderno:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Inicializa la variable id de la instancia cuaderno y al diccionario que contendrá el par _id : Nota()."""
        self._id = 0
        self.notas = {}

    def mostrar_nota(self, notas=None):
        """ Muestra todas las notas o las notas que se le pasen según el filtro. """
        if not notas:
            notas = self.notas
        for id_, valor in notas.items():
                print(f"{id_}: {valor.tags}\n{valor.mensaje}")

    def crear_nota(self, mensaje, tags=""):
        """ Crea una nota y le añade un identificador. El contenido de la nota es obligatorio, pero los tags no lo son. """
        self._id += 1
        self.notas[self._id] = Nota(mensaje, tags)
        print("Se ha creado una nueva nota.")

    def eliminar_nota(self, id):
        """ Elimina una nota con un id especificado. Si la nota no existe, muestra un mensaje. """
        if self.comprobar_nota(id):
            self.notas.pop(id)
            print("Nota eleminada.")

    def modificar_nota(self, id, mensaje="", tags=""):
        """ Modifica el tag o el memo de una nota según si se ha pasado o no el valor. """
        if self.comprobar_nota(id):
            """ Comprueba que el id de verdad exista """
            if mensaje:
                self.notas[id].mensaje = mensaje
                print("Mensaje modificado")
            if tags:
                self.notas[id].tags = tags
                print("tags modificados")

    def comprobar_nota(self, id):
        """ Método que servirá para comprobar que el id dado exista. """
        if id in self.notas:
            return True
        else:
            print("Nota no encontrada")
            return False

    def buscar_nota(self, criterio):
        return {id_: nota for id_, nota in self.notas.items() if nota.search(criterio)}
```

Comment: La iteración podría ser `{id: nota for id, nota in self.notas.items() if nota.search(criterio)}` no obstante creo que deberías separar los criterios ahora mismo buscas criterio en el propio mensaje y en las etiquetas sin discriminar ¿mensaje y tags que tipo de dato son?¿Cadenas ambos? Las etiquetas deberían ser una lista o mejor aún un conjunto.

Comment: Sí, ambos son textos.

No termino de entender la respuesta, la estudiaré un poco a ver si consigo aclararme. Llevo dos días liados con el programa y ando saturado.

Gracias.

Comment: Lo que es un diccionario es `self.notas`, cuyos valores son instancias de `Nota`. En tu código iteras sobre `self.notas`, lo que es lo mismo que iterar sobre sus claves, por lo que `nota.values()` es intentar usar el método `values` sobre la `id`, un entero... en todo caso, puedes iterar sobre los objetos Nota usando  `self.notas.values()`. Por otro lado, mencionas problemas con `modificar_nota`, también, pero no ve nada mal en ella en principio ¿cuál es el problema concreto que tienes con dicho método?

Comment: Creo que me he liado, con modificar nota no tengo ningún problema.

El problema viene en que no sé cómo hacer la parte del filtrado, por más vuelta que le doy, no consigo hacerlo. He mirado el código que me has pasado, pero no lo entiendo. ¿Podrías describirme qué hace? A ver si así consigo entenderlo? Gracias y perdona la torpeza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, `self.notas` es un diccionario en el que la clave es un valor numérico, la id, y el valor es una instancia de la clase `Nota`.

Vamos a analizar la línea de código del método `buscar_nota`:

```
{nota for nota in self.notas if nota.values().search(criterio)}
```

- **`{nota for ....}`**: esto crea un conjunto (`set`) usando una expresión generadora. No crea un diccionario porque la expresión no genera una pareja clave: valor, sino que en cada iteración retorna `nota` solamente.
- **`for nota in self.notas`**: esto itera sobre el atributo de instancia `self.notas` que es un diccionario. Cuando se itera con un `for in` sobre un diccionario, realmente se itera sobre sus claves:

  ```
  d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
  for k in d:
      print(k)
  ```

  > ```
  > 'a'
  > 'b'
  > ```

  Es por tanto equivalente a iterar sobre la vista generada por el método `dict.keys()`:

  ```
  d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
  for k in d.keys():
      print(k)
  ```

  Como tu diccionario `self.notas` tiene como claves la id, lo que retorna `for nota in self.notas` son dichas ids.
- **`if nota.values().search(criterio)`**: aquí tenemos el problema que causa una excepción directamente. Como hemos comentado, `for nota in self.notas` itera sobre las claves de `self.notas`, lo cual retorna la id, un entero. Por lo que `nota.values()` es intentar usar el método `values` de un objeto `int`, lo que lógicamente es imposible porque no existe.

En todo caso, podrías hacer algo como:

```
{self.notas[id_] for id_ in self.notas if self.notas[id_].search(criterio)}
```

o si quieres un diccionario con las ids similar a `self.notas`:

```
{id_: self.notas[id_] for id_ in self.notas if self.notas[id_].search(criterio)}
```

pero esto es complejo, feo e ineficiente. Si quieres iterar sobre las notas en si (instancias de `Nota`) almacenadas en `self.notas`, itera sobre los valores de dicho diccionario:

```
{nota for nota in self.notas.values() if nota.search(criterio)}
```

lo anterior crea un conjunto con las instancias de `Nota` para las que su método `search` retorna `True`. No obstante, supongo que la idea original es filtrar `self.notas` obteniendo un diccionario similar de la forma `{id: Nota()}`. Para ello, basta con usar el método `dict.items()` que itera sobre cada item de un diccionario retornándolo en una tupla de la forma `(clave, valor)`, en tu caso `(id, nota)`:

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
for item in d.items():
    print(item)
```

> ('a', 1)
>      ('b', 2)

al hacer `for clave, valor in dict.item()` simplemente desempaquetamos dichas tuplas en las variables `clave` y `valor`:

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
for clave, valor in d.items():
    print(f"Clave: {clave}, valor: {valor}")
```

> Clave: a, valor: 1
>      Clave: b, valor: 2

Por lo tanto, en tu caso debes hacer:

```
{id_: nota for id_, nota in self.notas.items() if nota.search(criterio)}
```

Si llegara a confundir la sintaxis de los "diccionarios por compresión", lo anterior es equivalente (aunque algo más eficiente) a:

```
notas = {}
for id_, nota in self.notas.items():
    if nota.search(criterio):
        notas[id_] = nota
```

Comment: Dios... No te imaginas como tengo la cabeza ahora mismo.

Te estoy muy agradecido por la ayuda. Soy nuevo en python y en programación como tal y tengo muchas dudas, tampoco me entero de muchas de las cosas que has explicado, pero eso ya es culpa mía, estoy muy verde y necesito darle más caña a todo este tema.

Mil gracias por la ayuda. Da gusto poder contar con una comunidad tan buena como esta.

Comment: Una duda que me surge, la variable id_ la has creado tú, ¿no? O la sacas de algún lado. Por otro lado, ¿por qué tiene _ al final?

Gracias!

Comment: `id` es un [builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) en Python (funciones predefinidas por defecto), generalmente hay que evitar usar el mismo nombre que alguno de los builtins porque lo solapamos (lo cual puede dar problemas si dicho builtin es directa o indirectamente usado en nuestro código). Aún sin dar problemas, puede ser confuso para otros usuarios, por ese en vez de `id` uso `id_`, por convención. En cualquier caso `id_` es una variable generada en el for.

Comment: Por la misma razón no debemos nombrar nunca a una variable `list`, `dict`, `int`, etc. En este caso dichas funciones además actúan como constructores de los objetos/tipos con el mismo nombre y sulen ser bastante más usados que `id`. Imagina que haces algo como: `list = [4, 5]`, si luego en el mismo espacio de nombres  intentas hacer algo como `lista_caracteres = list("Hola")` obtendrás un error, porque `list` ahora no hace referencia al builtin `list` sino a una lista, a un objeto `list` concreto (`[4, 5]`). Si no puedes usar otro nombre más descriptivo, por convención se usa un `_` al final.

Comment: De nuevo, mil gracias

Comment: @Man Recuerda aceptar esta pregunta si se ha resuelto tu problema a duda.

Comment: ¿Cómo se hace eso?

No tenía ni idea de que tenía que darla como aceptada.

Creo que ya lo hice.